# How to control the kestrel port during deployment?

Tags: .net, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-6.0

During development I control the http and https ports using the launchSettings.json file as marked below:

[image]

Is it correct to use this same approach to control the kestrel port during deployment to production? Or do I need to make any port config in the appsettings.json or any other file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `launchSettings.json` work for Development env [Development and launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson)

There are the several ways you can set the port in  [Kestrel endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for production environment

Specify URLs using the:

- `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable.
- use `dotnet` with `--urls` command-line argument.

  `dotnet yourdll.dll --urls http://+:2222`
- [`UseUrls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls?view=aspnetcore-6.0) extension method.
- `urls` host configuration key.

If we want to set a Kestrel endpoint Follow the node to set the URL for your project appsettings.

> Kestrel / EndPoints / Http / Url

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://+:2222"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**

But I would suggest you add `Nginx` or `Certbot` to be reverse proxy instead of setting port and expose to outside connection.

Comment: So the port value in `launchSettings.json` is irrelevant for production deployments?

Comment: @variable  `launchSettings.json` work for Development  env https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson

Comment: Ok, and what does `+` mean in `http://+:2222`?

Comment: @variable Host names, `*`, and `+`, aren't special. Anything not recognized as a valid IP address or localhost binds to all IPv4 and IPv6 IPs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#url-prefixes